# Crashes while exiting the ReactNative in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

**We found a ios crash when while exiting the ReactNative, ReactNative is part of our app，When the app exits from ReactNative to native，There was a crash，This is an occasional problem. Now we can not reproduce, and there is no exact path to reproduce this problem, only the general operation path described before and crash stack**

So far, I haven't used any solutions, can anyone help me? Thank you

This is the crash stack

```
Thread 29 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 29 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f28e7674 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20304b1ac pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1bc448c8c abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202f8ab8c abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202f89f34 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 32
5   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202f89eb0 std::terminate() + 36
6   AliyunLogProducer                      0x10433e6e4 CPPExceptionTerminate() + 316
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202f89f28 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
8   libc++abi.dylib                        0x202f89eb0 std::terminate() + 36
9   reacthermes                            0x1087f0aac facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::~SerialExecutor() + 152
10  reacthermes                            0x1087f0ae0 facebook::hermes::inspector::detail::SerialExecutor::~SerialExecutor() + 12
11  reacthermes                            0x1087ba660 facebook::hermes::inspector::Inspector::~Inspector() + 64
12  reacthermes                            0x108799e20 std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::hermes::inspector::RuntimeAdapter>::~shared_ptr() + 64
13  reacthermes                            0x1087896e8 facebook::hermes::inspector::chrome::Connection::Impl::~Impl() + 44
14  reacthermes                            0x108789788 facebook::hermes::inspector::chrome::Connection::Impl::~Impl() + 12
15  reacthermes                            0x10879870c facebook::hermes::inspector::chrome::Connection::~Connection() + 40
16  reacthermes                            0x1087b46cc facebook::hermes::inspector::chrome::ConnectionDemux::removePage(int) + 196
17  reacthermes                            0x1087b49e8 facebook::hermes::inspector::chrome::ConnectionDemux::disableDebugging(int) + 64
18  reacthermes                            0x1087b6fd4 facebook::react::(anonymous namespace)::DecoratedRuntime::~DecoratedRuntime() + 48
19  reacthermes                            0x108799e20 std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::hermes::inspector::RuntimeAdapter>::~shared_ptr() + 64
20  reacthermes                            0x1087b66b8 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::~JSIExecutor() + 272
21  reacthermes                            0x1087b68c4 facebook::react::HermesExecutor::~HermesExecutor() + 84
22  React                                  0x1079e2b00 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 32
23  React                                  0x1079f01fc facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 24
24  React                                  0x1079f0540 facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void ()>&&) + 164
25  cxxreact                               0x107e365ec facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::destroy() + 88
26  cxxreact                               0x107e2a0dc facebook::react::Instance::~Instance() + 36
27  React                                  0x1079df924 std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer<facebook::react::Instance*, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::Instance>::__shared_ptr_default_delete<facebook::react::Instance, facebook::react::Instance>, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::Instance> >::__on_zero_shared() + 20
28  React                                  0x1079dca44 __26-[RCTCxxBridge invalidate]_block_invoke + 904
29  React                                  0x1079e2b00 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 32
30  React                                  0x1079d80a4 -[RCTCxxBridge _tryAndHandleError:] + 100
31  Foundation                             0x1af1657cc __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
32  CoreFoundation                         0x1b4e98f24 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
33  CoreFoundation                         0x1b4ea52fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
34  CoreFoundation                         0x1b4e291c0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
35  CoreFoundation                         0x1b4e3eb7c __CFRunLoopRun + 836
36  CoreFoundation                         0x1b4e43eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
37  React                                  0x1079d7fdc +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 212
38  Foundation                             0x1af185518 __NSThread__start__ + 716
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2030456cc _pthread_start + 148
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x203044ba4 thread_start + 8
```